# OpenVPN doesn't resolve names when using a router

Tags: ubuntu, networking, router, dd-wrt, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN client (TCP TUN) on an Ubuntu box. For some reason, it stopped resolving names when I'm connected through my dd-wrt router. It used to work just fine, and when connected directly, it still works. Resetting the settings didn't help. Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Please give more information about your setup. Are you behind a DD-WRT router, trying to connect to an external OpenVPN server? Are you saying DNS is working when you connect directly to the Internet to your OpenVPN server, without being behind the DD-WRT router?

Comment: @GregoryA.Lussier Yes, this is exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I think of would be that your DD-WRT router is running dnsmasq and your PC gets its IP address as a DNS server. For some reason, it would keep it as a DNS server when it's connected to the VPN server. I don't see why it wouldn't do the same when it's directly connected though.

You may want to explicitly push a DNS server to your VPN clients:

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#dhcp